# Should I call Process.destroy() if the process ends with exit code 0?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec, exit-code

I have a process that is started via a Spring JMSListener. The process basically runs a Runtime exe to invoke imagemagick to do some reprocessing of an image.  Under *nix, there are threads that remain even though the Runtime exec command exits with exit code 0 and no exceptions are thrown. The app is using [Gythio Runtime Exec](https://github.com/Alfresco/gytheio/blob/master/gytheio-commons/src/main/java/org/gytheio/util/exec/RuntimeExec.java) class to perform its work.  Not withstanding the usual pitfalls around StdErr and StdOut that can arise with Runtime, which Gythio is handling correctly, shouldn't we destroy the process even though it was successful?

Here's a simple example, please ignore code errors its not meant to be real code. My question is around the // process done block:

```
public class Test {

    public void doSomething(String cmd, String processProperties, String processDirectory){

        try {
            // cmd is something like convert ... file .. params

            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

            final Process process = runtime.exec(cmd, processProperties, processDirectory);

            int exitValue = process.waitFor();

            System.out.println("exit value: " + exitValue);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("exec response: " + line);
                //log = line;
                //writeToFile(line);
            }
            // process is done... should it be destroyed? 
            if(process != null){
                process.destroy();
            }
            // end process done
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

After about an hour of running, the application running in tomcat shows these threads (where tomcat is pid 1641):

```
[root@server logs]# top -H -p 1641
top - 19:45:24 up 264 days, 10:33,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.19
Tasks: 5068 total,   0 running, 5068 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8061332k total,  6690912k used,  1370420k free,   195348k buffers
Swap:  1888252k total,    77672k used,  1810580k free,  5070148k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1734 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.3 12.0   3:03.41 java
1641 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.00 java
1643 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:01.20 java
1644 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:02.31 java
1671 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:02.28 java
1678 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:02.35 java
1686 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:02.20 java
1687 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   2:25.66 java
1688 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.11 java
1691 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.08 java
1706 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.00 java
1712 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:53.24 java
1720 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:39.38 java
1721 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:12.96 java
1722 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.00 java
1723 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   2:54.47 java
1724 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.00 java
1728 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:03.62 java
1729 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:08.16 java
1731 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.75 java
1732 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:02.58 java
1735 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:03.63 java
1736 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:02.23 java
1737 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:00.92 java
1738 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:03.59 java
1739 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:02.96 java
1740 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:05.07 java
1741 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:02.26 java
1742 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:04.57 java
1743 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   3:01.79 java
1744 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:26.27 java
1745 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.10 java
1746 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:10.72 java
1747 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.00 java
1748 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:10.99 java
5611 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.68 java
5620 adminuser  20   0 5842m 948m  13m S  0.0 12.0   0:00.36 java
```

Any/all replies are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they cleaned up if you close the stream (e.g. using a try-with-resources)?

Comment: You wouldn't think it should be necessary. You would think if the process has returned an exit code it has called `exit()` or returned out of main, so there is no process to destroy.

Comment: A program cannot exit (or return an exit code), until it has finished and the program has closed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your program is creating a non-trivial output.  When you run a program in the background it will write up the buffer size which could be just a few KB. Once the buffer size is reached it wait for the consumer, your program, to read the output.  This applies to standard out and error.

If you don't consume the output and error, your spawned program could wait forever, but you are waiting for the exit code first which will not happen, so you get a deadlock.

I suggest you use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), redirect the error to the output and read both to the end before waiting for the exit code.

From the example.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
File log = new File("log");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
Process p = pb.start();
// no need to copy the output
int exit = p.waitFor();
```

Comment: The example was merely to illustrate where I thought the class https://github.com/Alfresco/gytheio/blob/master/gytheio-commons/src/main/java/org/gytheio/util/exec/RuntimeExec.java may have needed a process.destroy(). If you look at the class, the lib is consuming the std out and errors, so I don't think its that. I tend to agree with the comments above by @EJP. Thanks though!

Comment: @Griff that code is very different to the one in your question.